# Debugging PHP in Sublime Text 3 with Xdebug

Tags: sublimetext3, xdebug

I have just got this set up, and I am wondering why the debugger stops not only at breakpoints but also at undefined variables and deprecated commands. All very nice, but not what I want it to do at the moment.

How can I control this so that it only stops at my defined breakpoints?

Comment: Aha ~ perhaps the file Xdebug.sublime-settings holds the key:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file Xdebug.sublime-settings contains the configuration for controlling when xdebug should stop at lines other than breakpoints, as follows:

```
{
    // Break on exceptions, suspend execution
    // when the exception name matches an entry in this list value.
    "break_on_exception": [
        // E_ERROR, E_CORE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR
        "Fatal error",
        // E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR (since PHP 5.2.0)
        "Catchable fatal error",
        // E_WARNING, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_WARNING, E_USER_WARNING
        // "Warning",
        // E_PARSE
        "Parse error",
        // E_NOTICE, E_USER_NOTICE
        // "Notice",
        // E_STRICT
        "Strict standards",
        // E_DEPRECATED, E_USER_DEPRECATED (since PHP 5.3.0)
        // "Deprecated",
        // 0
        "Xdebug",
        // default
        "Unknown error"
    ],   
}
```